# Чтение из файла длинного целого числа в указатель

Tags: c++builder, файлы, числа, c++

С++ Builder 2010 XE2

Друзья голова опухла от это длинной арифметики. Короче тупой вопрос.
Имеется файл в нем число целое офигенное большое число **>= 2^50** как без болезненно считать вот это добро в 
    string *temp_

как это сделать...

Вот перегруженный код оператора >>

```
istream & operator>> (istream &s, Verylong &v)
{
   //Тут было так:
   //char* t; s>> t (или t<< s)
   //несерьёзно в общем
    string temp_; 
    s >> temp_; (С++ Builder не канает!)

    char* temp = new char [temp_.size()+ 1];
    strcpy (temp, temp_.c_str());
    temp [temp_.size()]= 0;

    delete [] v.vlstr;
    v.vlen = strlen(temp);
    v.strrev(temp);
    v.vlstr = new char[v.vlen + 1]; assert(v.vlstr != NULL);
    strcpy(v.vlstr, temp);
    delete [] temp;

    return s;
}
```

И еще в С++ Builder не канает `s >> temp_;` Говорит что в операторе >> нету типа string как исправить это дело.

Короче мне нужно любая функция которая считвала бы правильно в массив `char* temp`.

И еще лучше было если это реализовано было бы не в стандартных потоках ввода и вывода.
А

> TEdit, TMemo

с компонентами C++ Builder'а

Comment: Ужас. Откуда такой класс был взят? Разве нельзя было инкапсулировать установку значения из строки в какой-нибудь метод или даже перегрузить operator= для string?

Comment: А что не канает-то?

    #include "VERYLONG.H"
    #include <sstream>
    int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
        Verylong a;
        string stringvalues = "125320512750333";
        istringstream iss (stringvalues,istringstream::in);
        iss >> a;
        cout << a;
        return 0;
    }

Оттранслировался и выполнился без проблем. Правда CBuilder'а  у меня нет, транслировал g++.

Comment: В g++ все без нарекании проходит и работает хорошо. Класс нашел в просторах сети. Не мой. Я в Билдере делаю а там как вызнаете все компоненты возвращают UnicodeString.

Comment: Нет, не знаю. CBuilder'а ни разу не видел. Но тут-то нет никаких компонент -- тут только c++'ные классы. Почему здесь-то не работает? Кстати, в CBuilder есть возможность компиляции из командной строки, как в MS VS?

А вообще, что сказать? Нахрен такие инструменты... Да и вообще, от продукции ф. Borland лучше держаться подальше -- как от пулемёта, который по своим стреляет.

Comment: Если C++Builder не поддерживает стандарт, причем в самой востребованной его части, то в топку его.

Comment: А может вместо этого Verilong взять на просторах сети gnu'сный gmp? Обёртка(и) для C++ там есть. И документация есть... И обёртки для delphi (самый борландовый инструмент)  есть...

@mikillskegg какие-то трения, созданные плавным переходом виндов на ucs-2. Интересно, какие глюки ещё вылезут от их фокуса с переходом от ucs-2 к utf-16?

Comment: Короче я портирую вот эту вот библиотеку-самокрутку для консольного вида
https://svncvpr.in.tum.de/cvpr-ros-pkg/trunk/cvpr-tools/symboliccpp/original/headers/verylong.h
В проект Билдеровский. Насчет по дальше держаться. Вы правы. Лучше уж на Qt чем на этом. Но увы лабы по ЭВМ в ВУЗе хреновом.

Answer (score 2):

Мне кажется, ваш подход неверен. Вот эта строчка:

```
s >> temp_;
```

считает в `temp_` слишком много, не заботясь о том, цифры это, буквы или пробелы.

Вам нужно делать по-другому: читать из потока по одному символу, накапливая промежуточный результат во временном `Verylong`, до первого неподходящего символа. Для этого неплохо бы сначала проверить символ (peek/get или get/putback). Не забывайте о переполнении!

---

Если ваше число не превосходит 2^63 по модулю, возможно, вы сможете использовать готовую встроенную процедуру по чтению <s>long long</s> `int64_t`?

---

Если вам нужен код, не использующий стандартные потоки (тот же `istream`), откуда тогда должна читать ваша процедура?

Comment: Этот код из готовой рабочей программы только для стандартного потока cin/cout. Я пытаюсь погодганть под билдер. Используя файлы для чтения чисел самих и вывода результата. Так как компоненты TLabel и TEdit не заполняются числами примерно после 3000 символов,а лучше было бы использовать для эти цели файлы. Сам этот класс Verylong использую переопределенные операторы >> и << для чтения и вывода на консоль. Я вот пытаюсь его пилить что он читал из файла и работал . Могу кинуть сам класс Verylong. Класс - длинная арифметика над целыми числами

Comment: @Рузэль: код совершенно очевидно очевидно неправильный; судя по всему, он используется только в ограниченном контексте. С произвольным файлом он не сработает. Перепишите его правильно. Как именно -- предложено в ответе.

Comment: А можно как нить вставить вместо s >> temp_; но вместо это точно используя while(!eof()) . Насчет проверки на число. Не надо. Данные верные записаны будут. Просто нужно считать из файла в массив string. И не обязательно в предопределенном операторе. Я потом этот код оберну в другую функцию. Просто проблема в чтении самого числа из файла. Пофиг пусть на string или char* дальше сам!

Comment: @VladD Вот сам класс
http://share.bashtel.ru/files/315774

Comment: @Рузэль: для чтения строки из файла используйте getline или что там подходит к вашему файлу (у C++ есть много способов доступа к файлам). В любом случае, для чтения одного числа вам _в принципе_ не может понадобиться чтение целой строки. Подумайте о таком файле:

    федя 314159265358979323846 математика
    вася 271828182845904523536 физкультура

-- что прочитается?

Comment: @Рузэль: тогда пожалуйста-пожалуйста-пожалуйста не называйте эту функцию `operator >>`. Потому что она делает не это.

Хорошо, а в чём тогда проблема? Вы не знаете, как прочитать содержимое текстового файла в строку?

Comment: @VladD Да вот в этом проблема. Прочесть файл полностью в char *temp .
Потому что вся логика этого класса крутиться вокруг char'ов.

Comment: @Рузэль: ну ёлки, http://lmgtfy.com/?q=read+string+text+file+c%2B%2B:

[`std::getline(is, s);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline)  
[`fscanf (f, "%s", str);`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fscanf)  
[`fgets(buf, sizeof buf, f)`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/fgets), ещё тысяча способов.